# Summarising data frame columns as rows with factor columns with R

Tags: r

I have a dataset where each row gives a number of Likert scores (1 to 5) for an individual.

```
   UseAgain Recommend ImprovedMx Comfortable EasyRead WearPt
1         4         3          4           4        3      3
2         4         4          2           3        2      2
3         4         3          4           2        4      1
4         3         4          3           3        2      3
5         3         3          3           1        3      1
6         3         4          2           2        3      3
7         4         1          3           4        2      2
8         5         2          2           4        3      3
9         2         5          3           3        3      2
10        5         3          1           4        2      4
```

For each column, I want to create a row in a new data frame that gives counts for each of the factor levels. As follows:

```
            StronglyDisagree Disagree Neutral Agree StronglyAgree
UseAgain                   0        1       3     4             2
Recommend                  1        1       4     3             1
ImprovedMx                 1        3       4     2             0
Comfortable                1        2       3     4             0
EasyRead                   0        4       5     1             0
WearPt                     2        3       4     1             0
```

Here's the code I am currently using to achieve this:

```
dm <- melt(data)

count.fac <- function(fac) {
  tapply(dm$value, dm$variable, function(x) {sum(x == fac)})
}

ds <- data.frame(
  StronglyDisagree = count.fac(1),
  Disagree = count.fac(2),
  Neutral = count.fac(3),
  Agree = count.fac(4),
  StronglyAgree = count.fac(5)
)
```

I'm looking to improve or simply my code for this manipulation.

Comment: Haven't tested, but something like: `t(sapply(dat, function(x) table(factor(x,levels=1:5,labels=c("SD","D","N","A","SA")))))`

Comment: @thelatemail, you might want to point out that the first (accepted) answer in the duplicated link may not work with OP data (at least didn't with a `read.table` version thereof for me), and that they need to rely on a modified version of yours (though I had to use `labels=levs` and `levels=1:5`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t(table(stack(DF)))
```

Produces:

```
             values
ind           1 2 3 4 5
  Comfortable 1 2 3 4 0
  EasyRead    0 4 5 1 0
  ImprovedMx  1 3 4 2 0
  Recommend   1 1 4 3 1
  UseAgain    0 1 3 4 2
  WearPt      2 3 4 1 0
```

I didn't relabel the factors, but that is trivial.